# Java: Why are my JButtons being painted behind the background image?

Tags: java, swing, button, paintcomponent

Here is the JPanel class that is having the issue:

```
public class EntryDialog extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

MainWindow         mainWindow;
Image              background;
JButton            continueresume;
JButton            newresume;
JButton            settings;
JButton            exit;

public EntryDialog(MainWindow mainWindow){

    continueresume            = new JButton("Continue resume");
    newresume                 = new JButton("New resume");
    settings                  = new JButton("Settings");
    exit                      = new JButton("Exit");
    this.mainWindow           = mainWindow;
    this.background           = Utilities.getImage("images\\entryDialogBackground.jpg", true);

    this.setLayout(null);

    //continueresume button
    continueresume.setBounds(Utilities.getScaledWidth(1150), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(150), 
            Utilities.getScaledWidth(500), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(50));

    //newresume button
    newresume.setBounds(Utilities.getScaledWidth(1150), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(220), 
            Utilities.getScaledWidth(500), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(50));

    //settings button
    settings.setBounds(Utilities.getScaledWidth(1150), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(290), 
            Utilities.getScaledWidth(500), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(50));
    //exit button
    exit.setBounds(Utilities.getScaledWidth(1150), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(360), 
            Utilities.getScaledWidth(500), 
            Utilities.getScaledHeight(50));

    this.add(continueresume);
    this.add(newresume);
    this.add(settings);
    this.add(exit);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(background != null){
        g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

This JPanel is being painted to a main frame in another class. What is happening is "background" is being painted just fine, but the buttons are not. The buttons appear once I hover over them with my mouse but until then they are invisible. I have searched for hours and not come to a solution so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it happens when you choose not the same pane or the order in which you added the components to the container.

Comment: @RomanC "happens when you choose not the same pane"..I'm sorry can you elaborate? I am not sure what you mean by this. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you satisfied with the answers? Why do you want to elaborate on me?

Comment: @RomanC I was asking what you meant by "happens when you choose not the same pane"...

Comment: It's really doesn't matter now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd have to guess it's happening in your paintComponent method.  You're calling super.paintComponent() will draw everything like usual including the buttons.  Then you're drawing over it with g2d.drawImage().  You should draw the background first.

Comment: I tried adding the line super.paintComponent()  to the end of the paintComponent method and this did not fix the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Try setting the opacity of the JPanel to false through setOpaque.  That way the JPanel's paintComponent method won't draw it's background over yours.

Comment: I tried setting the opacity to false however nothing changed; The JPanel still painted the image over the buttons.

Comment: You're doing both suggestions I made though right?  Draw before calling super.paintComponent() AND setting the opacity to false?  I have a little example right now that just does that and it has buttons that draw fine.

Comment: Yeah the code is the same as my original post, however I added super.paintComponent(g) to the end of the paintComponent(Graphics g) method and I added this.setOpaque(false) underneath this.setLayout(null). It's strange that it is working for you but not for me, maybe it has something to do with the frame that is having added this JPanel class?

Comment: I changed g2d.dispose() to g2d.finalize() and this worked. I'm only asking you because you've been the most helpful, but would you happen to know if there might be unintended side effects in doing this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Ahh I think I know what's up.  Calling finalize() is something you shouldn't be doing (pretty much ever, that's for the GC to call), the same with dispose() because you didn't make the Graphics object.  I think what's happening is you were deleting the graphics object via dispose before it finished doing something.  Try it without a call to either.  Tested this on my example by adding g.dispose() and I get odd drawing too.  Without it should work, which is what you did by changing to finalize().

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `dispose` on the graphics object you didn't create!

Comment: @anon Thank you so much. Nearly every example online includes the call to dispose() which is unfortunate but now I know. I appreciate it.

Comment: `paintComponent` is called BEFORE `paintChildren`.  Disposing of the graphics context means `paintChildren` has nothing to paint to. @anon Could you update you answer to reflect your discovery within the comments so that any one else with the same problem doesn't have to read through the components to find the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a JFrame too in which you place this panel. Try calling the frame last after everything which is gonna be in it is already initialised.

I had the same problem last year and this fixed it for me.

Comment: I am passing the JFrame into the constructor of the JPanel class so I can reference it... how would I cal the frame after the JPanel class if this is the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
/*Use this code as an example first run this and then use it for your requirements*/
package mypack;



import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class backgroundClass extends JPanel {

//Initializing the class Image
Image background;

//Setting up GUI
public backgroundClass(interfaceAndImage iai) {

 //Constructing the class "Toolkit" which will be used to manipulate our images.
 Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

 //Getting the "background.jpg" image we have in the folder
 background = kit.getImage("d:\\123.jpg");
}

//Manipulate Images with JAVA2D API. . creating a paintComponent method.
 public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {

  //Constructing the class Graphics2D. Create 2D by casting the "comp" to Graphics2D
 Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D)comp;

 //creating a graphics2d using the images in the folder and place it in a specific coordinates.
     comp2D.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
 }
}
```

/*Another class*/
    package mypack;

```
//Java Core Package
import javax.swing.*;
//Java Extension Package
import java.awt.*;

public class interfaceAndImage extends JFrame {

//Constructing the class we created called "backgroundClass" so we can
//use it here in our main program as a parent panel.
backgroundClass bc;

//Initializing our JComponents and the labels of our JButton and JLabel
JPanel panel1, panel2;
JLabel labels[];
JButton choices[];
JTextField inputs[];
String lebelName[] = {"Name:","Age:","Sex:","Address:","Tel. No.:"};
String buttonChoice[] = {"Register","Reset","Cancel"};

//Setting up GUI
public interfaceAndImage() {

 //Setting up the Title of the Window
 super("How to put a JTextField, JLabel, and JButton above image");

 //Set Size of the Window (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
 setSize(310,170);

 //Exit Property of the Window
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 //Constructing the class "backgroundClass" and call the keyword "this" so it can
 //be recognizable by our main program.
 bc = new backgroundClass(this);

 //Constructing JPanel 1 and set its layout property including the background property
 //which is transparent
panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

//Constructing the class Color and set its property to 0,0,0,0 means no color.
Color trans = new Color(0,0,0,0);
panel1.setBackground(trans); //Setting JPanel 1 background to transparent


 //Constructing JPanel 2 and set its layout property
panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout());

//Constructing our JComponents setting its specific array size
 labels = new JLabel[5];
 inputs = new JTextField[5];
 choices = new JButton[3];

 //Adding our JPanel 1 and 2 to our class "backgroundClass" which is our parent panel
 bc.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 bc.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

 //Setting up the container ready for the components to be added.
 Container pane = getContentPane();
 setContentPane(pane);

 //Constructing JLabel and JTextField using "for loop" in their desired order
 for(int count=0; count<inputs.length && count<labels.length; count++) {
  labels[count] = new JLabel(lebelName[count], JLabel.RIGHT);
  inputs[count] = new JTextField(30);

  //Adding the JLabel and the JTextFied in JPanel 1
  panel1.add(labels[count]);
  panel1.add(inputs[count]);
 }

//Constructing all 4 JButtons using "for loop" and add them in the panel 1
 for(int count=0; count<choices.length; count++) {
  choices[count] = new JButton(buttonChoice[count]);
  panel2.add(choices[count]);
 }

//Adding the class "backgroundClass" to our container as parent panel
pane.add(bc);

 /**Set all the Components Visible.
  * If it is set to "false", the components in the container will not be visible.
  */
 setVisible(true);

 //Disable window size
 setResizable(false);
}

//Main Method
public static void main (String[] args) {
 interfaceAndImage iai = new interfaceAndImage();
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also use image button